# QT1070 inconsistent readings on touch pins

Tags: i2c, atmel, qtouch

I recently transitioned my projects capacitive touch IC from using the [MPR121](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/MPR121.pdf) to the [QT1070](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-9596-AT42-QTouch-BSW-AT42QT1070_Datasheet.pdf).

I am getting irregular/inconsistent readings on one of the touch pins.  In this particular situation, it is `Pin 7` (which equates to "key6" from the docs).  The pin keeps changing its state from touch to untouched, seemingly at random.

Does anyone have any experience operating this chip, particularly in comms mode with I2C?

I am using the schematic below (from the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-9596-AT42-QTouch-BSW-AT42QT1070_Datasheet.pdf)), and am using 4.7k resistors on all the touch pins.

[image: schematic]

Is it possible I have to play around with this "detect threshold" business from the docs?

> `Detect Threshold`
>   The device detects a touch when the signal has crossed a threshold level and remained there for a specified number
>   of counts (see Section 5.10 on page 19). This can be altered on a key-by-key basis using the key threshold I2C
>   commands.

I should note that the resistors are not attached to anything, as it is currently operating on a bread board.

Comment: When you say the resistors are not attached to anything, does that mean that you do not actually have keys? You are just touching the resistor leads?

Comment: Ya that is correct. Is this... wrong? I figured it would be the same as connecting the resisters to a copper pad, unless I am greatly misunderstanding how 'capacitive touch' actually works haha

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular device, but yeah, that definitely sounds wrong. The amount of capacitance between a finger and a lead is going to be way lower than the amount of capacitance between a finger and a pad.

Comment: The datasheet mentions 6mm x 6mm pads or larger on the first page (although it doesn't include it as an actual spec--crappy datasheet). Solder a pad onto the resistor lead and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which stabilized the readings.

What I ended up discovering with the QT1070 chip is that you can in fact set a **sensitivity threshold** for each individual pin.  The sensitivity has to be a value between `1` and `255` and can be set like this:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(chip_address); //  0x1B
Wire.write(38); // adress for pin 6
Wire.write(200); // sensitivity value between 1 - 255
Wire.endTransmission();
```

The [SeeedQTouch](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Seeed_QTouch/blob/master/Seeed_QTouch.cpp) library has a function called `setNTHRForKey(value, key)` you can use to make this step easier.